# ReferenceError: mangoose is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Node is throwing the 'ReferenceError: mangoose is not defined' at me.

It states that the error is in this line:

`const dogSchema = new mangoose.Schema({`

I have instelled mongoose by npm

`$ npm i mongoose`

And here's the code

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhose:27017/fruitsDB")

const fruitSchema = new mangoose.Schema({
```

Can anyone recognise what the problem is?
I've required mongoose in the .js file and installed it via npm.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

You have a typo in line 3 of your code. It should be mongoose, not mangoose.

Comment: That's embarrassing. Thank you!

Comment: It's ok, sometimes we overlook the small details when we think the problem is somewhere else. :)

Answer (score -1):

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhose:27017/fruitsDB")

const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
```

"mongoose" was spelled "mangoose" on line 3